# Multiple domains in one .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains linked in one FTP, and for me need rewrite .htaccess file, for work like that:

```
site.lt (redirect)-> site.lt
site.lt/lv (redirect)-> site.lt
site.eu (force redirect)-> site.eu/lv
```

now I have wrote this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.(lt|eu)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.(lt|eu)/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://site.eu/lv [R=301,L]
```

and it works like:

```
site.lt (redirect)-> site.eu/lv
site.lt/lv (redirect)-> not working
site.eu (redirect)-> site.eu/lv
```

how to rewrite htaccess to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.lt$
RewriteRule ^(lv)?/?$ / [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.eu$
RewriteRule ^$ /lv [R=301,L]
```